# how to create / print a user-defined (input) array with no limit for input in a for-each function

Tags: javascript

```
- Prompt the user to enter the word list and assign the input to a variable. Consider using the prompt() method to retrieve the user’s input. ..* Example: var input = prompt(‘Enter words separated by a space’);
- Split the word list where the separator is a space " ". Assign it to a variable. Consider using the split() method to split the word list on the spaces. Example: var wordList = input.split(" ");
- Create another array to store the number each word appears in the list of words (array).
- For each word in the list of words (wordlist), check to see if each word exists in the list (array). Consider using the forEach() method. This method is called once for each element in the array, in order. Example: wordList.forEach ( …….); HINT: Inside of the forEach() method consider using a branching statement to determine if the word exists in the list. If it exists, increase the counter. If it doesn’t exist, keep the counter at 1.
- Print each word along with the number the word exists in the list. Consider using the forEach() method again to print each element in both arrays.
```

I have done all of the above steps, however, just need help printing the number of times the word appears. In my console.log statement, the word prints to the console, so now I just need help figuring out how to print the frequency the word appears in the word list.

```
function calcWordFrequencies(){
var input = prompt('Enter words separated by a space');
var wordList = input.split(" ");
var wordCounts = { };

wordList.forEach(
    function(word) {
    if(word in wordCounts)
    {
        wordCounts[word] = wordCounts[word] + 1;
    }else{
        wordCounts[word] = 1;
    }//end of if/else statement
}//end of function
);//end of for-each function
wordList.forEach(
    function(word) {
    console.log(word + wordCounts);
}
);
}
```

here is an example of what a random output should look like:

```
hey 1
hi 2
Mark 1
hi 2
mark 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function calcWordFrequencies(){
    var input = prompt('Enter words separated by a space');
    var wordList = input.split(" ");
    var wordCounts = { };

    wordList.forEach(
        function(word) {
        if(word in wordCounts)
        {
            wordCounts[word] = wordCounts[word] + 1;
        }else{
            wordCounts[word] = 1;
        }//end of if/else statement
    }//end of function
    );//end of for-each function
    for(let word in wordCounts)
    { 
      document.write(word + " : " + wordCounts[word] + "\n");
    } 
  }
```

This should print the way you want i think.

Comment: It says "the body of for should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties in the prototype" in the program I'm using as an error - I'm using Komodo edit. I also submitted this to the autograder I'm using as well to submit the assignment, and it did not show any input to the screen.

Comment: I'm using the autograder I have to use for my class, and it's showing up as an empty input and gave me a zero. Thank you though, I do see how its working on that link.

Comment: My teacher also said this if this helps. "You must print the words with their frequencies in a forEach() method. Also, when you render your page in Komodo, be sure to render the index.html page and in your javaScript console you run the calcWordFrequencies() method. The last curly brace that you have on line 17 is the closing curly brace for the entire function. Your forEach method you need to print the final values has to be above that final closing brace. "